# Create address via API no longer working with Webform CiviCRM?

Tags: api, webform-civicrm

Since upgrading to Civi 4.7.28, webform submissions via the Drupal 7 module "Webform CiviCRM" have not been able to create a new address in a new CiviCRM contact. In the error log, I have these errors:

> The CiviCRM "address create" API returned the error: "A fatal error was triggered" when called by function "preSave" on line 178 of wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc with parameters:...

Are others having the same problem? I'm not clear whether it's a fault with the Drupal module or the Civi API. I can't recreate in the CiviCRM sandbox as I don't think that has the Webform module operational.

UPDATED FOLLOWING COMMENT.
Here is the backtrace:

```
 $backTrace = 
0:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(336): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) 
1:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1101): CRM_Core_Error::fatal()
2:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php(1008): CRM_Core_DAO::getFieldValue("CRM_Core_DAO_Address", "null", "master_id") 
3:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php(157): CRM_Core_BAO_Address::fixSharedAddress((Array:16)) 
4:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Address.php(83): CRM_Core_BAO_Address::add((Array:16), TRUE)
5:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_address_create((Array:16)) 
6:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(169): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:9)) 
7:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(100): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:9)) 
8:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(23): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("address", "create", (Array:15), NULL) 
9:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/utils.inc(1534): civicrm_api("address", "create", (Array:15)) 
10:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc(819): wf_civicrm_api("address", "create", (Array:15)) 
11:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/includes/wf_crm_webform_postprocess.inc(178): wf_crm_webform_postprocess->saveContactLocation((Array:14), "1276", 1) 
12:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/webform_civicrm.module(222): wf_crm_webform_postprocess->preSave(Object(stdClass)) 
13:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/webform/includes/webform.submissions.inc(151): webform_civicrm_webform_submission_presave(Object(stdClass), Object(stdClass)) 
14:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/webform/webform.module(3394): webform_submission_insert(Object(stdClass), Object(stdClass))
15:/htdocs/includes/form.inc(1520): webform_client_form_submit((Array:34), (Array:26)) 
16:/htdocs/includes/form.inc(904): form_execute_handlers("submit", (Array:34), (Array:26)) 
17:/htdocs/includes/form.inc(386): drupal_process_form("webform_client_form_1688", (Array:34), (Array:26)) 
18:/htdocs/includes/form.inc(131): drupal_build_form("webform_client_form_1688", (Array:26)) 
19:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/webform/webform.module(2061): drupal_get_form("webform_client_form_1688", Object(stdClass), FALSE, FALSE) 
20:/htdocs/sites/all/modules/webform/webform.module(2330): webform_node_view(Object(stdClass), "form") 
21:/htdocs/includes/module.inc(926): webform_block_view("client-block-1688") 
22:/htdocs/modules/block/block.module(911): module_invoke("webform", "block_view", "client-block-1688") 
23:/htdocs/modules/block/block.module(690): _block_render_blocks((Array:2)) 
24:/htdocs/modules/block/block.module(319): block_list("content") 
25:/htdocs/modules/block/block.module(270): block_get_blocks_by_region("content") 
26:/htdocs/includes/common.inc(5901): block_page_build((Array:4)) 
27:/htdocs/includes/common.inc(2748): drupal_render_page((Array:4)) 
28:/htdocs/includes/common.inc(2621): drupal_deliver_html_page((Array:1)) 
29:/htdocs/includes/menu.inc(542): drupal_deliver_page((Array:1), "")  
30:/htdocs/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() 
31 {main}
```

There was also a geocoding error logged at the same time, but I don't know why this happened, as we only add a few addresses each day, and I don't see that this should trigger a fatal error:

> $Geocoding failed. Message from Google: (OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) = You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. We recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_

Comment: Could you please post a [debug and backtrace](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/#debugging) to help folks answer you?  Note that you'll probably need to use the "CiviCRM log" method because you're triggering this error from Drupal, not Civi itself.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I've added the backtrace in the original question above and also noticed that a geocoding error was logged at the same time.

Comment: Thanks! That illuminates things. I see the code that's causing the crash. It's meant to prevent misuse of the "address sharing" feature. However, it seems like this situation should specifically not trigger that code. As a next troubleshooting step please:

* open `<civiroot>/CRM/Core/BAO/Address.php`
* Find this line (around 137): `public static function add(&$params, $fixAddress = FALSE) {`
* Insert the following line just below it: `CRM_Core_Error::debug_var('myparams', $params);`
* Retrigger this bug and search your CiviCRM log for "myparams".  Update the question with the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this issue, you should [apply this patch to your CiviCRM code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/72e28791a51587c534c3f516407e5d8bf07d2402) (which wasn't merged in time for 4.7.29).

You'll find more information on this issue on [this pull request](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/11324) and on this issue: [CRM-21214](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-21214) .

Cheers,
Olivier;